# Fancybox not run on eleganttheme's theme

Tags: wordpress, fancybox

Integrated fancybox in my theme not run.
I've read another post about, in this forum, but I don't understand what was solution.
My web site is:
http://www.costruzionimartini.com/

thanks

Comment: You have a few Javascript errors relating to your social stuff - Facebook and stumbleupon.  Plus there is some issue with that search.I.js file you are loading in.  Sort those out and then take it from there.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about the error you have with Fancybox?

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to use the plugin [easyfancybox for wordpress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fancybox/) since it brought Elegant Themes compatibility in version 1.5.0.